# Python Procedural or Object Oriented

Tags: python, oop

I am new to programming and do not fully understand the difference between an object-oriented language and one that is procedural. What is the difference and what category does python fall under?

Comment: Python is both procedural  and have object-oriented features, as well as some aspects of functional programming. That is what is meant when one says that Python is multi-paradigm.

Comment: I would encourage you to explore the topic on internet (including Youtube videos) - there are some great resources available on this. Here's a starting point: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-procedural-and-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, here are some general definitions regarding the different types of programming languages:

“ Functional programming (FP) is a programming paradigm — a style of building the structure and elements of computer programs — that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and mutable data.” — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

“ Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of “objects”, which may contain data, in the form of fields, often known as attributes; and code, in the form of procedures, often known as methods.” — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

“ Procedural programming is a programming paradigm, derived from structured programming, based upon the concept of the procedure call. Procedures, also known as routines, subroutines, or functions, simply contain a series of computational steps to be carried out.” — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming)

As for **Python**,

[Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) supports both Object-Oriented and Procedural Programming approached as it is a high level programming language designed for general purpose programming. That is what people mean when they call it "multi-paradigm"